# Storing one dimensional array to two dimensional

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I am trying to split and store an ArrayList in a two dimensional array.
I am able to split every ArrayList item by ":" character. Later I am able to store the result returned by the split function in one dimensional array.

My ArrayList content is as follows:
a:b:c:d:e
p:q:r:s:t:u:v
m:n:o

Now, I would like to store the result in two dimensional array.
I followed the following approach:

```
String a[]={};
String array[][] = {};

for(int i=0;i<abc.size();i++){
    a = abc.get(i).split(":");

    for(int j=0; j<a.length; j++){
        array[i][j] = a[j];
    }
}
```

But, I am getting ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
        at com.exp.users.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Could anyone please share how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array is initialized incorrectly. Should start out as `new String[abc.size()][]`, not `{}`. Also, you must initialize nested arrays to `new String[a.length]`. Full code:

```
List<String> abc = Arrays.asList("a:b:c:d:e", "p:q:r:s:t:u:v", "m:n:o");
String a[];
String array[][] = new String[abc.size()][];
for(int i=0;i<abc.size();i++){
    a = abc.get(i).split(":");
    array[i] = new String[a.length];
    for(int j=0; j<a.length; j++) array[i][j] = a[j];
}
```